# why visual studio give different link error when i try to link multiple libraries at once?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, glfw, porting

I have been trying to make a game using c++ on code::blocks, since the code became large and it needs to be optimize. I decided to port my project to visual studio due to its better profiling tools and all other stuff. And i ran into some linking problem.

(Note: all the libraries are build targeting 64bit platform and i am building my project targeting 64bit platform on "Windows 10")

My game project uses these libraries "glew, glfw, bullet and assimp" i have build all of these libraries using visual studio by myself, these all works fine but individually when i tried to link all of them with my project source. And compiled i got this

Build log image:

[image]

I really don't care about those warnings(I know those warnings are about compiler change i will solve them) but my actual worry is those linking problem because the libraries work for other projects(those i linked for testing purpose) but give error in this one only when i try to link them all at once. I am linking statically using /MT  and i tried -NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT but it is not working. Thanks in advance!

NOTE: Sorry if the question format is disturbed because this is my first time post.

Comment: Post the log, not the image of a log. Was everything built with the same `/MT` flag?